# WSO2 BPS 3.5.0 source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I try to build wso2 bps 3.5 from source code by following document (https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/Working+with+the+Source+Code), but there is no org.wso2.carbon.humantask_4.4.4.jar inside the downloading component. Also I cannot find the source code in svn (https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/business-processes/humantask/org.wso2.carbon.humantask/).

Can somebody help to figure out where is this code repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/), this is released with carbon 4.4.x where sources are in Git repos. So the sources should be available in [this Git repo](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-business-process) (checkout the correct branch version). Note that you don't have to build the entire product from sources, just do the changes to the relevant component and build the jar. Then apply it as a patch to the product.

Comment: btw, did you run performance test on business process server? I got deadlock on  20 users to invoke bps. The detail is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756320/database-deadlock-in-wso2-bps-when-creating-human-task

Comment: it seems that question is already answered by a BPS product developer.